# Empty leaderboard style ad

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, advertising

I recently joined a new site, so I get the joy of seeing ads again.

This add struck me as odd
[image]

<strike>Inspecting the page also revealed no hint of any actual add container being present.</strike>
The HTML of the page does show the iFrame:

> `<iframe style="border: 0px none; vertical-align: bottom;" src="https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/safeframe/1-0-37/html/container.html" id="google_ads_iframe_/248424177/wordpress.stackexchange.com/lb/question-pages_0" title="3rd party ad content" name="" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" data-is-safeframe="true" data-google-container-id="1" data-load-complete="true" width="728" height="90" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

but trying to copy the inner HTML of the iFrame results in nothing. 
 Inspecting that HTML element from within the inspector reveals that it has a height of 0.

Now I'm all for loading the page without making it jumpy, but there should be better use for this valuable real-estate then just white, right?
Also the "Report this ad" button is fully functional, and I reported the ad (or lack thereof) successfully.

I am not deploying an ad-blocker or any userscript.
Browser: FF 68.5.0esr on macOS 10.14.6

Refreshing the page just lead me to the same. An empty add frame.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask the obligatory comment :). I have none.

Comment: While trying to reproduce, noticed some ads loading for long time. The placeholder is shown, then ad loading. So maybe slow connection? Fix can be catching the timeout error (or a timer, e.g. one minute), that will hide the placeholder if ad didn't load.

Comment: Not that I know of @ShadowWizardWearingMask, the tab is still open, and still the same is shown.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask I edited the post a bit.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for pointing this out. We've received your ad report as well (which adds some data about what should've been shown), and with that could find the partner that was running this ad. We'll reach out to them to see whether it was just a glitch or something that should be fixed.

*Disclaimer: I'm an employee of Stack, working as a Product Manager in the Advertising team*

Comment: Good to know that functionality works as well ;)